# Biased bootstrap: how to construct confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, cross-validation, bootstrap, bias

For a project I am trying to evaluate a set of predictors using logistic regression. So I have defined a model selection procedure that I applied on the data, and estimate an AUC to assess model performance. To validate the model selection procedure, I perform a leave-one-out cross-validation, stacking individual predictions and estimating a "validated" AUC on these predictions.

The challenge now comes when I try to find a confidence interval for this validated AUC. My approach was to perform a bootstrap with 1000 iterations, doing the LOOCV on all resampled data sets. However, there is a large difference between the observed validated AUC and the bootstrapped AUCs (the latter being substantially larger). Only 6 out of 1000 bootstrapped AUCs were as small as the observed one or smaller.

This results in a percentile based CI (I used the [basic bootstrap CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Methods_for_bootstrap_confidence_intervals)) that does not cover the observed AUC. What can I do in this situation? What does it mean when there is such a large difference between observed AUC and bootstrap mean?

See the boxplots below for the bootstrap results of 3 different quantities (AUC's based on different sets of variables). For the third AUC (clinical+imaging), the value I found on the observed data is 0.525, which is even below the .025 quantile.

[image: Bootstrap results]

Comment: Do you have some results / images / code to show us? Otherwise it is hard for us to answer.

Comment: @user2974951 does the edit help? I highlighted the worst of the 3 quantities I bootstrapped.